# How to delete a single line of log in the log stream of cloudwatch logs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

We have a website that has logs stored in AWS CloudWatch Logs. The log stream contains many different customers' data.

Our boss says that if any one of our customers asks us to delete his/her data, we must be able to do so. He said that this is one of the requirements of [GDPR](https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-data-protection/guide-to-the-general-data-protection-regulation-gdpr/individual-rights/right-to-erasure/).

I have found methods to filter out the logs that belong to a specific user. My problem is that I can't delete the filtered logs.

Is it possible to delete a single line of log in CloudWatch Logs?

The [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/index.html) doesn't seem provide any ways to delete a single line in the logs of CloudWatch.

Or should I use a different approach to handle the logs so that I can meet the boss's requirement?

Comment: If you look at the [API doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) you'll see that the only delete operations are for groups and streams. So you'll have to store your logs somewhere else.